# SQL scripting, pertaining to correlated sub queries

Tags: sql

I have been having difficulties with a piece of script I am creating, and was hoping for some insight into what I am doing wrong

QUESTION:

use a correlated subquery to return invoice(s) for each vendor, representing the vendor’s oldest invoice (the one with the earliest date). Each row should include these four columns: vendor name, invoice number, invoice date, and invoice total.

MY SCRIPT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Vendor_Name,
    Invoice_number AS OLDEST_INVOICE,
    Invoice_date,
    invoice_total
FROM Vendors v
JOIN Invoices i ON v.vendor_id = i.vendor_id
WHERE invoice_date IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT MIN(invoice_date)
        FROM invoices i
        JOIN vendors v ON i.vendor_id = v.vendor_id
        GROUP BY v.vendor_name
        )
ORDER BY Invoice_Date;
```

Currently, my code is giving too many results back, essentially I am having trouble establishing that invoice_numbers are only to be returned for the lowest date possible.

Comment: 0_o This is homework, isn't it?

Comment: Yes the question is homework, my script is what I came up with based off of the question.  My professor has yet to respond to any questions I have had, so this is where I am :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restrict the join to those invoices for the specific vendor, AND that has the earliest date...
 You don;t menmtion whether the Invoice table has a surrogate PK... If it doesn't, try:

```
 SELECT 
    v.Vendor_Name,  
    i.Invoice_number as OLDEST_INVOICE,  
    i.Invoice_date,  
    i.invoice_total  
 FROM Vendors v  
 JOIN Invoices i 
     ON i.vendor_id = v.vendor_id
        And i.invoice_date =
            (Select MIN(invoice_date)
             From Invoices
             Where vendor_id = v.Vendor_Id)  
ORDER BY i.Invoice_Date;
```

If the invoice table has a surrogate PK, say InvoiceId, then try this:

```
 SELECT 
    v.Vendor_Name,  
    i.Invoice_number as OLDEST_INVOICE,  
    i.Invoice_date,  
    i.invoice_total  
 FROM Vendors v  
    JOIN Invoices i 
       ON i.InvoiceId = 
          (Select InvoiceId
           From Invoices
           Where vendor_id = v.Vendor_Id
              And Invoice_Date =
                   (Select Min(Invoice_Date)
                    From Invoices
                    vendor_id = v.Vendor_Id))
ORDER BY i.Invoice_Date;
```

The former only uses one subquery, but the latter is truer (more clearly expresses) the intent of the query's intent.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to you is not to use a sub-query in a `WHERE` clause but instead use a derived table in an inner `JOIN`.

```
SELECT
  v.Vendor_Name, 
  i.Invoice_number as OLDEST_INVOICE, 
  i.Invoice_date, 
  i.invoice_total 
FROM Vendors v 
JOIN Invoices i ON v.vendor_id = i.vendor_id 
JOIN (SELECT 
        i2.vendor_id, 
        MIN(i2.invoice_date) AS min_invoice_date
      FROM invoices i2 
      GROUP BY i2.vendor_id) minv 
  ON minv.vendor_id = v.vendor_id 
   AND minv.min_invoice_date = i.invoice_date
ORDER BY i.Invoice_Date;
```

Comment: Missing expression in that script, I can't seem to locate it.

Comment: @JOEBENJAMINBLACK the problem was the distinct in the derived table.  I have corrected the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help, this was an interesting way to do this, tough to understand but I think I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon your platform, this can be written a little more concisely (and a little easier to understand using analytical window functions):

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/sql/0596004818/sql-functions/sqlnut2-chp-4-sect-3